# Can I recover data created on a CAINE linux live usb

Tags: linux, data-recovery, usb-drive

Long story short I had to do a mock static exam for my college digital forensics class. I went through and screenshotted stuff and then copied it to a usb export drive that i mounted. All is well and dandy however when i got to compiling all my data all the files show 0mb and are unopenable. What i am wondering is if i can recover anything off the live usb drive? I did a hard shutdown so theres a chance it may still be somewhere on the drive, not sure how to get it off.

To note i did look for a casper-rw file and that does not exist on the drive

Comment: You can try first with `testdisk` and if no luck with `photorec` (which means a lot of work), but it is often possible to recover a lot from the memory cells even without a partition table. See [this link](https://cgsecurity.org). - But if the drive was live (live-only) and not persistent live, your data were only stored in RAM, so lost after shutdown.